# Syncdb not working

Tags: python, django, django-imagekit, syncdb

```
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill
```

class Product(models.Model):

```
class Meta():
    db_table = 'tovar'


product_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
product_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
avatar_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='avatar',processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],format='JPEG',options={'quality': 60})
product_categories = models.ForeignKey(Category)
product_subcategories = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
product_description = models.TextField()


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.product_title


profile = Product.objects.all()[0]
print(profile.avatar_thumbnail.url)    
print(profile.avatar_thumbnail.width)
```

Dont working manage.py syncdb

Error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: tovar

pls healp me

Comment: did you try manage.py migrate ?

Comment: I deleted my database. And cant create new one. My syncdb command tells me "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: tovar" .

Comment: All operation with database tells me error:"django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: tovar"

Comment: can you post the database part of your settings.py?

Answer (score 2):

'python manage.py syncdb' doesn't work for Django 1.9 or later, try this code!

- python manage.py makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate
- python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

I have the same problem with Django 1.9 and 1.10. This code works!

Answer (score 0):

If you have modified your model you first have to run

`manage.py schemamigration your_django_application_name --auto`

Then you run:

`manage.py migrate your_django_application_name`

Comment: No, the command to create a migration is `makemigrations`, and it doesn't have an `--auto` flag.

Comment: That's why I said at the beginning "If you have modified your model you first have to run"

If he is initializing the app he could run

`manage.py schemamigration your_django_application_name --initial`

And then migrate as said in the south documentation

http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

Comment: But why are you recommending South? Migrations are now built into Django, there is no indication that OP is using an old version.

Comment: Not any indication at all he was using migrations that's why I suggested he could check them this way.

Answer (score 0):

use the below command

```
>>python manage.py sqlmigrate  application_name 0001
```

if you have more tables then increment the number to ooo2 and run the abe code again

```
>>python manage.py runserver
```